# Base64 decoding "Input is not valid Base64 string"

Tags: .net, vb.net, base64

Why cant I decode Base64 using this code? It says `"Input not valid Base64 string, because it contains characters that are not the Base-64 encoding, or more than two fill characters or contains invalid characters between fillings."`

My code is

```
    Dim base64_Encoded As String = "YXNkZg=="
    Dim bt64 As Byte() = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64_Encoded)***
    Dim text As String = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bt64)
    MsgBox(text)
```

where `YXNkZg==` = `asdf` and `***` is the place where it gets stuck.

Comment: Works for me: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8xlBJe -- Make sure you haven't gotten any invisible characters in there. Also, you should probably switch from `Unicode` to `UTF8` instead. Unicode gives me chinese characters.

Comment: If it is VB.NET it cant be vba and we dont need language tags in the title - it is just noise and redundant.

Comment: @VisualVincent thanks a lot, works fine

Comment: So mine worked? Then you have gotten (an) extra invisible character(s) in yours. Voting to close this as caused by a typographical error.

Comment: @VisualVincent Voting same, thanks a lot